# Separate graphql/relay backend and frontend

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, sangria

I would like to separate my backend and my frontend with different projects using relay. The reason I'm doing this is because I'm using a particular relay/graphql backend, sangria and would like to keep the frontend development separate from the Scala development.

Would it be possible to connect a react relay frontend application on one server communicating to another graphql server backend. It seems everywhere that relay assume that its endpoint is on the same host with endpoint /graphql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The docs on [Relay's network layer](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/guides-network-layer.html#content) might be useful to you:

> By default, Relay assumes that GraphQL is served at /graphql relative
>   to the origin where our application is served. This can be
>   re-configured by injecting a custom instantiation of the default
>   network layer.
>
> ```
> Relay.injectNetworkLayer(
>     new Relay.DefaultNetworkLayer('http://example.com/graphql')
> );
> ```

Make sure that your graphql server allows cross-domain requests using CORS headers.